# Avoid Empty Sub-Tags in XML if everything is blank in an object

Tags: xml, jaxb

We have JAXB objects marshing/unmarshalling XML. Currently, we get this tag, even though everything inside it is empty. **We need to completely get rid of the Top section if all its sub-elements are empty.** (If at least one is not empty, it should exist.)

```
    <ns2:Top>
        <ns2:OrganizationName></ns2:OrganizationName>
        <ns2:Address>
            <ns2:Street1></ns2:Street1>
            <ns2:Street2></ns2:Street2>
            <ns2:City></ns2:City>
            <ns2:ZipPostalCode></ns2:ZipPostalCode>
        </ns2:Address>
    </ns2:Top>
```

The JAXB class is defined as:

```
    @XmlElement(name = "Top")
    protected Top top;
```

Comment: "Get rid of" when? Do you have this XML and do you need to transform it? Is it marshalled like this and you want it skipped? - Do you have an XML Schema defined and how does it look like?

Comment: Objects are constructed and we marshal to XML. If the object above only contains empty objects (though not NULL), we need to make it NULL. Right now that's not happening, and we get the full hierarchy of empty objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the amount of elements appearing in the marshalled XML by setting or not setting fields.

```
Root root = new Root();
root.setTop( new Top() );                   // (1)
root.getTop().setAddress( new Address() );  // (2)
```

With lines (1) and (2), marshalling produces

```
<root><top><address/></top></root>
```

With just line (1), the XML will be

```
<root><top/></root>
```

Omitting both lines yields

```
<root/>
```

Once you have organizationName or address or both set in Top with some or all String fields set to the empty string (i.e., "") you'll have to write some code for pruning the useless fields. (Although it is highly questionable to set fields to the empty string if there isn't a useful value to be used.)

**Later** An adapter is a good idea. Annotate the element you want to keep, Top, or the one above it:

```
@XmlElement
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter.class)
protected Top top;
```

And write an adapter to investigate the object hierarchy, replacing it with an empty top level element:

```
public class Adapter extends XmlAdapter {
    public Top unmarshal( Top v ) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    private boolean allEmpty( String... strings ){
        for( String s: strings ){
            if( s != null && ! s.equals( "" ) ) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Top marshal( Top top ) throws Exception {
        Address a = top.getAddress();
        return allEmpty( top.getOrganizationName(),
                         a.getStreet1(), a.getStreet1(),
                         a.getCity(), a.getPostalCode(),
                         a.getState(), a.getCountry() ) ? new Top() : top;
    }
}
```

I have chosen Top, so you keep an empty `<top>`, but you can do this one level higher.

Comment: Our objects always exist as a result of SpringMVC Form binding. It looks like if you bind a GUI field to a field in this JAXB-generated class, all the objects in the hierarchy are created. For example, a Street1 GUI field is bound to "top.address.Street1", and it's automatically expanded when saving the form. But we need something that will compress the object if nothing exists underneath, maybe an Adapter or something?

Comment: An adpapter is a good idea - see the addition to my answer. -

Comment: Thanks. That's what we'll do.